# Inserting HTML inside quotes

Tags: html, tooltip, page-break

I want a page break inside the title attribute of a link, but when I put one in, it appears correct in a browser, but returns 7 errors when I validate it.

This is the code.

```
<a href="images/Bosses/Lord Yarkan Large.jpg" class="hastipz" target="_blank" title="Lord Yarkan, a level 80 Unique from Silkroad Online -- Click for a Larger Image">
<img class="bosspic" src="images/Bosses/Lord Yarkan.jpg" style="float:right; position:relative;" alt="Lord Yarkon; Silkroad Unique"/>
</a>
```

The reason is because the title attribute appears in a tooltip, and I need a page break inside that tooltip. How can I add a page break inside the quotes without returning errors?

Comment: Do you mean line break or page break?  And what are you trying to validate this under?  When using HTML 5, at least, you can enter page breaks inside the title attribute and receive no errors.  Or do you want the line break to occur inside the title itself?  If so use Gringo's character entity technique.  You might need `&#x0A` instead of `&#13;` depending on the platform....  (Possibly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to validate for work?

If not, do not worry about the errors if it works as you want it.

Validation is not the goal.  It is a tool to help build better Web sites. which is the goal. ;-)

If you must have it validate, you could try to use some script to switch out a specific keyword / set of characters for a `<br />` at dom ready.  *Although this is untested and I am not sure it wouldn't throw errors, too.*

**EDIT**

As requested, a little jQuery to switch out a word:

```
$('a').each(function(){
    var a = $(this).attr('title');
    var b = a.replace('lineBreak','\n');
    $(this).attr('title', b);
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/qRQaq/1/

Nb:

1. I used "lineBreak" as the keyword, as this is unlikely to be matched.  "br" might be
2. I replaced it with the `\n` line break character.
3. You should try the `\n` line break character on its own... might work without needing to replace anything.

Comment: I'm not very skilled at Javascipt, I wouldn't know where to begin to make a script that replaced a keyword with a page break. Would you know how to write a script like that? Make the keyword "br".

Comment: It works on my page, but it doesn't remove "lineBreak" it just inserts "\n" I'm using chrome to test it. I realize it should though because you're using the replace function, so I could take out "lineBreak" and replace it with "\n"

Comment: Strange @Mark!  Anyway, as I mentioned above, you may want to just add the `\n` if it works for you and passes the validation.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this forum post](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum21/10973.htm):

```
    There are two approaches:

    1) Use the character entity for a carriage return, which is &#13; Thus:
    <...title="Exemplary&#13;website">

    (For a full list of character entities, try Googling "HTML Character Codes".)

    2) to do any additional styling to your "tooltips", Google "CSS tooltips"
```

1) is Non-standard though. Works on IE/Chrome, not with Firefox.  The [new spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dom.html#the-title-attribute) appears to recommend &#10; (newline) instead.

Comment: Very good answer, however none of those things worked. The only thing I can think of is using javascript to replace a keyword in the title attribute with a page break. Unfortunately, I'm not skilled enough in javascript to write a script like that.